# Error using buttongroup as dropdownitem in Reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I need a ButtonGroup as a DropdownItem.

```
 <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
        <DropdownToggle caret>
          Dropdown
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownItem toggle={false}>
            <ButtonGroup>
               <Button>Right</Button>
               <Button>Right</Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
          </DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
 </Dropdown>
```

I get the warning:

```
warning.js:33 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <button> cannot appear as a descendant of <button>.
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have a button rendered inside a button.  That said the DropdownItem component has a tag property of "button" by default which means that it will render a button.  If you would change the property to tag="h1" on the DropdownItem for instance it would render an h1 instead and you would not have this error.  Hope i am clear.

Comment: You can have a look in the reactstrap DropdownItem.js code you will see how it's built.